# Equation of current in charging of capacitor

Tags: circuit-analysis, passive-networks

How can I find the equation of current in the following circuit, when switch is closed at t=0. Capacitor is initially not charged.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFyjRp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: If there is **not resistance** (also no internal resistane in the voltage source, switch or capacitor) there is not much of an equation.... i.e. the equation is \$V_C(t)=0\$ for \$t<0\$ and \$V_C(t)=V_s\$ for \$t>0\$

Comment: What will be the nature of current ?

Comment: In ideal case (R=0) current will be infinite for an infinitely short time after switching on. In practice there will be some resistance R and you'll get a \$I(t)=I_0e^{-\frac{t}{RC}}\$ where \$I_0=\frac{Vs}{R}\$.

Comment: That means capacitor will be charged within a very short time, to the source voltage; doesn't that changes the property of capacitor of sudden change in voltage, "capacitor does not allow sudden change in voltage across it" ?

Comment: As I said: in practicy there is always some resistance. Therefore current will not be infinte and charging time will be >0. So voltage change will be in practice not "suddenly".

Comment: That is the problem when you suppose that there are ideal elements. An ideal capacitor CANNOT be connected to an ideal voltage source because the resultant current would be infinite. In reality there would be a very high current or even it could happen a puncture of the capacitor.

Comment: You could also ask what would be the equation of a switch shortcutting a power source. V/0 -> infinite current

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no equation.

With an ideal voltage source and ideal switch, wires and capacitor, infinite current is taken for an infinitesimal length of time to charge the capacitor to Vs instantly.

Answer (score 0):

Your schematic makes only sense if theres a series resistor between the capacitor and the power source.

In this case the voltage and current waveforms for charging the capacitor are:

\$ V_{cap}(t) = V_s \cdot \left( 1 - e^{-t/\tau}\right) \$ and

\$ I_{cap}(t) = C \cdot \frac{dV_{cap}(t)}{dt} = C \cdot V_s \cdot \frac{1}{\tau}\cdot e^{-t/\tau} = V_s \cdot \frac{1}{R}\cdot e^{-t/\tau}\$

where \$ \tau = R \cdot C\$

---

It all results from the equation:
\$ I(t) = C\cdot \frac{dV(t)}{dt}\$. This is the characteristic eqaution for a capacitor.

If you have a series resistance in your schematic and use the KVL You get:

\$ V_s  = V_R(t) + V_{cap}(t)\$.

With

\$ U_R(t) = R \cdot I_{cap}(t) = R \cdot C \cdot \frac{dV_{cap}(t)}{dt}\$

you get:

\$ V_s = R \cdot C \cdot \frac{dV_{cap}(t)}{dt} + V_{cap}(t) \$

you can solve this differential equation using different methods, for example using Laplace Transform.

The solution is the equation above.

---

The circuit without resistance doesn't produce a waveform. If you close the switch, the voltage change on the cap would be infinitely high which results in an infinite current. The capacitor is charged to its full voltage instantly.